# Check for mouse press while mouse moves

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple program that randomly moves my mouse to farm hours on sites like VHL. I want to add a section of code that stops the code from running when the mouse button is pressed.
So far I have this:

```py
# imports

import random
import time

import pyautogui

# screen resolution - 2256, 1504


while True:  # constantly runs, constantly updates variables

    # vars that need to update part

    posX = random.randint(0, 2256)  # get a random x coordinate
    posY = random.randint(0, 1504)  # get a random y coordinate
    randDuration = random.randint(2, 10)  # get a random duration for mouse movement
    randSleep = random.randint(5, 100)  # get a random sleep time

    # code part

    pyautogui.moveTo(posX, posY, randDuration)  # moves cursor to random coordinates from defined variables
    print(f"Cursor moved to x:{posX} y:{posY} in {randDuration} seconds!")
    time.sleep(randSleep)

    from pynput.mouse import Listener


    def is_clicked(x, y, button, pressed):  # function that stops code after mouse1 is pressed
        if pressed:
            exit()


    with Listener(on_click=is_clicked) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Everything works fine, but I want to be able to stop the program while the mouse is moving. In other words, while the line below runs:

> pyautogui.moveTo(posX, posY, randDuration)

I want to simultaneously check if the mouse 1 button is being pressed. 
Please let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For starters, do not import a module and define functions in a loop. Both actions should be executed only once.

Comment: I only add to @DYZ comment - put imports at the beginning of code so everyone could see what modules are needed to run this code.

Comment: as I know `moveTo` has no method to stop it. You may have to create own function to move mouse which will use loop to move mouse few pixels and check if button wasn't clicked, and then repeat this loop again and again.

Comment: you can use `print(pyautogui.__file__)` to get path to source code and see how it works or event copy it to create own function which will stop when you click button.